# Woocommerce Local Pickup Plus Plugin setup issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using local pickup plus plugin to show diferrent shipping methods when the country is set to **Malta** only.

My problem is,if someone is chosing diferrent country then Malta the **local pickup plus** **should be hidden** ,but it still shows.

I have made a shipping zone for diferrent countries which calculates shipping without the local pickup.

As you can see here
[image]

Can any of you help me fix this ?Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a javascript function to hide that text if the dropdown's selection is anything other than Malta.
It's hard for me to give you a specific answer with the limited info you gave, but this could help get you started:

include a reference to jQuery in your site (possibly already there)
include this in your javascript files

```
$('.your-drop-down-id').change(
    function() { 
        if (this.val == 'Malta') {
            $('.your-text-to-toggle-id').show(); 
        else 
            $('.your-text-to-toggle-id').hide();
    });
```

Comment: Arrigton how do i do that ? can you guide me ? thank you

Comment: Thank You i will see and try to figure it out .